# bash: XY: command not found; when XY is an existing alias

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, vim, alias

I've just noticed that when I call `fc`, I got the following error message:

```
zoltan@adrian ~ $ fc
bash: vi: command not found
```

The which command returns a similar result:

```
zoltan@adrian ~ $ which vi
which: no vi in (...intentional omission...)
```

The strange part of it is that I always just type "vi" when I use an editor. I've set up an alias in my .bashrc which will alias "vi" to "vim".

Could you provide an explanation why is this the case? Is it possible that these (built-in) commands open a subprocess with a non-bash shell, even if it is called from bash?

Is there any better workaround than putting a link named `vi`, which points to `vim`?

Comment: `which` doesn't know anything about shell aliases, functions, or builtins; use `type` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
export FCEDIT=vim
```

in your `.bashrc` to set the editor to `vim` instead of the default `vi`. This should take care of the error message and let you edit your commands.